# Delete An Object And Make It In Another Collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I Want To Get An Object > Make An Object Like It But In A Different Collection > Delete That Object

Here Is My Route Code:

```
//Move To History Case Route
app.delete('/case/delete', (req, res) => {
    Case.findById(req.body.id, (err, found) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            CaseHistory.create({
                name: found.name,
                description: found.description,
                paid: found.paid,
                assigned: found.assigned,
                date: found.date,
            }, (err, created) => {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    Case.findByIdAndDelete(req.body.id, (err, deleted) => {
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err)
                        } else {
                            res.send(created)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

and Thanks A Lot

Here Is The Schema:
And The Other Schema Is Similar To It

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    paid: Number,
    assigned: String,
    description: String,
    date: String,
    number: Number,
});

const CaseHistory = mongoose.model('History', Schema);

module.exports = CaseHistory;
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: It Deletes But It Deletes The First One In Order

Comment: Not The One I Have Chosen